# Google Cloud Functions: Correct module needed for app_identity to get the APPLICATION_ID

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do I import the app_identity module correctly within a Python Google Cloud Function so I can retrieve the `APPLICATION_ID`/`PROJECT_ID`.

As a lot of solutions are specifically tailored for Google App Engine deployments, this would be helpful. I deployed a GCF and imported the `app_identity` module with this code:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
```

I got this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first-generation App Engine modules (`google.appengine`) only exist within the original Python 2.7 runtime. They aren't available for the Python 3.7 runtimes on Cloud Functions or App Engine.

Instead, you can just get these things out of environment variables:

```
import os
project_id = os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT']
function_name = os.environ['FUNCTION_NAME']
```

Comment: Thanks, Dustin, I will try this fix and see if it works!

Comment: @DaltonWhyte, could you then please mark this answer as a solution then? This way everybody will see that this question was solved.

Comment: @dustiningram this saved my day. Thank you.